# how to write pure query script select, update delete and insert in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im new in laravel and I dont want to waste my time to finding away the eloquent script to running my complex query script, is there is a way for me.
for just write the query script (select , insert , update , delete) I have, to the laravel project and everything is work as I want ?

this bellow my sample code for select data, I want to replace the eloquent with pure query script

```
function getClaim(){
        $data_claim = \App\ClaimModel::all();
        return response()->json(
            [
                "message" => $data_claim
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: All of that you should find in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database). Check all "Database" sections though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

Insert query

```
$insert = DB::insert("insert into some_table (col1, col2, col3) values ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')");
```

Select query

```
$results = DB::select("select * from some_table where some_col = 'some_value'");
```

Update query

```
$update = DB::update("update some_table set col1 = ? , col2 = ? where col3 = ?", ['value1' , 'value2', 'value3']);
```

Delete query

```
$delete = DB::delete('delete from some_table where col = ?',['value']);
```

You can also delete multiple rows at a time. Like

```
$delete = DB::delete('delete from users where id = ?',[1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

    return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

For Select query

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

For Update query

```
$affected = DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);
```

For Delete query

```
$deleted = DB::delete('delete from users');
```

For Insert query

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);
```